# PTIJ: Where can I find Masechet Bava Maiseh?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

When I was in elementary and high school yeshiva, I learned Masechet [באָבע־מעשׂה](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bubbe-meise)‎, occasionally. It was an interesting Masechta that had a lot of unusual stories like how numerous people had lost all 3 of their eyes when they looked at a Cohen 3 times while he was *duchening*.

We had handouts of these stories and we didn't learn the entire Masechta. But, I assumed that it would be around in Seder *Nezikin* following *Bava Batra*, or, maybe before *Bava Kama*. But, it's not in *Nezikin*.

I can't find it in any other Seder. Then, I'm thinking, maybe it's one of those *Meschtot Ketanot* like *Kallah*. But, it's not there, either. Perhaps, *Bava Maiseh* is so small that I can't see it?

Can someone help me find it and tell me which Seder it's in?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Everyone in my family says that my grandmother is the master of bava maiseh. I'll ask her next time I see her.

Answer (score 8):

As we know, the text we now have in written form in the talmud was originally given as oral law.  It was only written down when we were in danger of losing it due to the persecution of our people.

What is less well-known is that it wasn't *all* written down.  Chazal decided to preserve this one small part in oral form only, as a remembrance of the original status of the larger body.  For this part that was to be preserved orally, they entrusted it to a group who Roman and other persecutors usually dismissed as irrelevant -- women, specifically older women.  A woman isn't even allowed to start learning it systematically until she's at least 40 and has had children, my grandmother said, though we have all heard pieces of it here and there.  She didn't start sharing teachings from it with us until she was about 70.  I don't have kids, so I'm not eligible to learn and don't know all the details of what can be taught to whom.

As for the order, Baba Maiseh is the last tractate in Nashim.  It has only *mishna*, no *g'mara*.

Comment: As my grandma would say ... "There's no maiseh like bubbe's maiseh's". Nice explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Right [here](http://matzav.com/in-honor-of-purim-5777-maseches-fake-news/).  Baruch Shekivanta!